# Postgres: Only return results that do not have letters

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a list of order numbers either following the format AB1234 or 123456. I need to set my query to only pull back order numbers that have letters in the first two characters. Thoughts?

Comment: what about ABC123?

Comment: Only the first two characters will ever contain letters. The next 4 will always be numerical.

Comment: That's a no brainer, use RegEx, see the first answer.

Answer (score 2):

This matches first two alphabet chars:

```
where order_number ~ '^[[:alpha:]]{2}'
```

or using char ranges for English only alphabets:

```
where order_number ~ '^[a-zA-Z]{2}'
```